# html5:how to align multiple div without shifting away when changing browser

Tags: javascript, html, css

The issue I have is that I made a table, and some arrows separately on different div. But those div can not move and become bigger or smaller **simultaneously** if I change a browser or zoom in the page.

Currently what I am doing is constructing a big table. Inside this big table, there are many small tables: for each row of the blocks, it is a table, so how many rows there are how many tables. The arrows are in a new div, its position is "absolute", I change the left/top position to adjust its position.

Could anyone suggest how can I solve this issue, thanks in advance.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Dupont Model</title>
<style type="text/css">

.table {            //for tables
position: absolute;
width: 633px;
height: 309px;
left: 0px;
top: -35px; 
}

.NetMarginArrow {
    Position: absolute;
    width: 180px;
    height: 115px;
    left: 428px;
    top: 166px;
}

<------each arrow is asigned with a div class--->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h3> Model</h3>     


    <div class="table">   <!--for tables (each block)-->

    <table  style border="0" cellpadding="0"> 

<!---a big table contains many small tables---->

        <td><table border="0" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10">
        <tr><td bgcolor="#C4E1FF"><b>Net Profit</b></td><td></td></tr>
        <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#F0F0F0"> {{net_profit}}</td>
        <tr><tr><tr>
        </tr>
        <tr><td bgcolor="#C4E1FF"><b>Sales</td></b></tr>
        <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#F0F0F0"> {{sales.sales__sum}}</td>
        <tr><tr><tr>
        </tr>
        </td></table>     

        <td><table border="0" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10">
        <tr><td bgcolor="#D2E9FF"><b>Gross Margin</b></td><td></td></tr>
        <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#F0F0F0"> {{gross_margin}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <tr><td bgcolor="#D2E9FF"><b>Tax</b></td><td></td></tr>
        <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#F0F0F0"> {{tax}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <tr><td bgcolor="#D2E9FF"><b>Total Expenses</b></td></tr>
        <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#F0F0F0"> {{total_expenses}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td></td></tr><tr><td></td></tr><tr><tr>    
        </td></table> 

    </table>
    </div>          

    <!----each arrow has a div---->
    <div class="NetMartinArrow">        
        <td><table border="0" cellpadding="0">  <!--Arrow after Net profit--> 
            <td>&larr;<td><table style="height:230px;width:15px;border-color:000000;border-top-style:solid;border-left-style:solid;border-bottom-style:solid;border-width:2px"><tr><td valign="top"></td></tr></td></table>
        </td></table> 
    </div>
    ............................same to all arrows.............     

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is likely due to your use of `position: absolute;`. Please can you provide a reproducible example, the code your provided doesn't really help demonstrate your issue.

Comment: Also, your HTML has errors. Missing start tags; end tags in the wrong places etc. If you correct those, does the problem persist?

Comment: I have put the whole code on it. I checked if removing position:absolute, it will not be the thing I want.

Comment: Thanks for posting your code. Unfortunately as @MrLister says, you have a lot of syntax errors in your code which a) make it difficult to look into the issue and b) could actually be causing the problem. I would suggest you take a look at these first. For example, you have tags being closed in the wrong place (`<td bgcolor="#A6FFA6"><b>Asset Turnover</td></b>` - `</b>` should be before `</td>`), missing opening tags (`<table border="0" cellpadding="0"><td>` - no `<tr>`) and random tags with no purpose (`<div class="CurrentAssetArrow"><td>` - `<td>` is unnecessary).

Comment: Thanks a lot @ Hidden Hobbes for your 3 suggestions. I have corrected the </b> thing; the second one regarding table, I didn't add the <tr> because it is actually a big table outside, and several small tables inside on the same line so for this one I didn't add <tr>; There are many <td>,<tr>..thing actually I want to make the distance between different blocks bigger. Yet these don't impact the result, I tried today to make a parent div (main) which position is relative, and contains the several child div which position is absolute, but they still cannot change the position simultaneously.

Comment: Honestly, instead of using tables for all this, you should really just use `absolute` positioning for **everything** on the page, and don't try to mix tables and absolute positioning. What you're really building here is more like a graphic than a table, and the built-in table layout systems are getting mixed up with the absolute positioning stuff. It's not a perfect solution, but at least you can get it the way you want it.

Comment: This might be a bit of a radical idea, but using SVG+XML instead of HTML here would make a bit more sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure where in code you are using the .NetMarginArrow css class. Also, css is case sensitive. In your code, 'p' is capital of position in .NetMarginArrow class.
Make sure that html body is taking 100% height. The container acts as a wrapper for all your elements.
Please try the code below.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Dupont Model</title>
<style type="text/css">

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

#container {
    position: relative;
} 

.table {            //for tables
position: absolute;
width: 633px;
height: 309px;
left: 0px;
top: -35px; 
}

.NetMarginArrow {
    position: absolute;
    width: 180px;
    height: 115px;
    left: 428px;
    top: 166px;
}

<------each arrow is asigned with a div class--->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h3> Model</h3>     

<div id="container">
    <div class="table">   <!--for tables (each block)-->

    <table  style border="0" cellpadding="0"> 

<!---a big table contains many small tables---->

        <td><table border="0" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10">
        <tr><td bgcolor="#C4E1FF"><b>Net Profit</b></td><td></td></tr>
        <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#F0F0F0"> {{net_profit}}</td>
        <tr><tr><tr>
        </tr>
        <tr><td bgcolor="#C4E1FF"><b>Sales</td></b></tr>
        <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#F0F0F0"> {{sales.sales__sum}}</td>
        <tr><tr><tr>
        </tr>
        </td></table>     

        <td><table border="0" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10">
        <tr><td bgcolor="#D2E9FF"><b>Gross Margin</b></td><td></td></tr>
        <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#F0F0F0"> {{gross_margin}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <tr><td bgcolor="#D2E9FF"><b>Tax</b></td><td></td></tr>
        <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#F0F0F0"> {{tax}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <tr><td bgcolor="#D2E9FF"><b>Total Expenses</b></td></tr>
        <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#F0F0F0"> {{total_expenses}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td></td></tr><tr><td></td></tr><tr><tr>    
        </td></table> 

    </table>
    </div>          
</div>
    <!----each arrow has a div---->
    <div class="NetMartinArror">        
        <td><table border="0" cellpadding="0">  <!--Arrow after Net profit--> 
            <td>&larr;<td><table style="height:230px;width:15px;border-color:000000;border-top-style:solid;border-left-style:solid;border-bottom-style:solid;border-width:2px"><tr><td valign="top"></td></tr></td></table>
        </td></table> 
    </div>
    ............................same to all arrows.............     

</body>
</html>
```

I have added container as a wrapper for all your HTML elements.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that your problem could be "or so I think" that you may need to use the percent sign, %. I know that in my first day or so of creating HTML that I learned the hard way that % is better than PX, BECAUSE, if you swap to a different resolution, a problem similar to that of which you are speaking of will arise. So try using 1-100% on your page. I believe it makes it scalable, and is relative to your current screen. Anyway, Do try that. In the case that I underexplained a little: by using percents you may achieve something along the line of being able to do something like this:
`<div id="EXAMPLE" style="height:1%;length:100%;"></div>`
This would effectively make a DIV element stretching the Entire page and taking up 1% of the screen's relative height, starting from the top of the page. This works with Positioning, and any other place where "PX" May be used, there is also "EM's" and other ways to do it, but I use % personally. That is all.

Comment: Hi@Turtles, sorry for my late reply. I tried something like this for all arrows and table as well:NetMarginArrow {
 Position: absolute;
 width: 1%;
 height: 3%;
 left: 5%;
 top: 6%;
}. The position of table and arrows still not move simultaneously...

Answer (score 3):

keep everything **fixed** on their places.
 div { **position:fixed;** }

and use
 #someid { **position:relative;** } for appearence of arrows at respective places

Comment: If I understand you correctly, it is to make table as fixed and all arrows div as relative. This way doesn't work.